# mongodb error on Cloud Functions for Firebase on production

Tags: mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I started playing around with Cloud Functions for Firebase, I did all the setup locally and run `firebase serve` and tested my `get` and `post` with mongodb setup in mlab.

I did a `firebase deploy` which deployed fine, then now I got home, was going to play around more.  I used postman and trying to make a post on production.  Somehow I get errors that Cloud Functions crashes

I can see that it seems like it's not connecting with mongodb with this error

> MongoDB connection error: { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [dsxxxxx.mlab.com:xxxxx] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN dsxxxxxx.mlab.com:xxxxx]
>
> name: 'MongoNetworkError',
>   message: 'failed to connect to server [xxxxx.mlab.com:xxxxx] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN dsxxxxx.mlab.com:xxxxx]'

Does anyone know what I am missing that the production deploy isn't working?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What payment plan is your project on?

Comment: @DougStevenson the free plan, ah...after you asked...I went to check it says free's outboud network is google service only which means if I switch a paid plan, it should work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firebase projects on the free Spark plan are not able to make outgoing socket connections to services that are not controlled by Google.  If you'd like to make an outgoing connection, [upgrade your payment plan to Blaze](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).  You'll likely still not be billed, as there are generous free quotas for usage that should cover small development projects.

Comment: thank you :D maybe I will try to use pay as you go and see how it works out.

But I do believe this is the answer even though I didn't try.  Huge thanks :D I tried debugging this for hours last night :(

Comment: It's unfortunate that the error message from mongodb isn't the same the the typical error messages that come from similar failed http requests.  :-(