# google cloud functions connect to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I am trying to connect to MongoDB in my google cloud function HTTP trigger.

```
'use strict';
const http = require('http');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
exports.weatherWebhook = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  MongoClient.connect('string', (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      db = client.db('chatbot')
      db.collection('chatbot_params').save({ "loanType": "123", "loanAmount": "90000", "duration": "5 years", "userSession": "test-1234" }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          res.json({ "status": "err" })
        } else {
          res.json({ "status": "saved" })
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

but when I run the program I get an error saying that.

```
ReferenceError: db is not defined at MongoClient.connect
(/user_code/index.js:14:16) at result
(/user_code/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:414:17) at
executeCallback (/user_code/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:406:9)
at /user_code/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:272:5 at
connectCallback
(/user_code/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:946:5) at
/user_code/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:816:13 at
_combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

why is that? I have implemented the same code in my other applications(not cloud functions). it seems to be working fine.

> **NOTE:** I am using mongo lab to host the database

Comment: Calling out to non-Google services from Cloud Functions requires that your project is on a paid plan. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248637/mongodb-error-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-on-production

Comment: Is your case what the comment by @FrankvanPuffelen describes? If not please define your mongourl, i.e. `const mongoURL = 'mongodb://my-db-user:my-db-password@ds131531.mlab.com:31531/my-db-name';`

And then this line should be: `MongoClient.connect(mongoURL, (err, client) => {...`. Then this small change: `let db = client.db('my-db-name')`

Also remember to include mongo in your package.json file:

`{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^2.2.5"
  }
}
`
I have tested this in `https://mlab.com` and it works without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please specify url for the MongoClient , as now you are just passing 'string' as url option.Have a look below

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) { // provide mongo lab url 
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  client.close();
});
```

Hope , this might will help you